# How to convert nested array to comma separated in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extract values from a nested array to a comma-separated string like below. for example, let `$data_array` is an array and it's when it `var-dump($data_array)` the output looks like

```
array(1) {
     [0]=> array(5)
        {
            [0]=> array(2) 
            {
                ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 1" ["vote_number"]=> string(1) "5" 
            }
            [1]=> array(2)
            {
                ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 2" ["vote_number"]=> string(2) "10" 
            } 
            [3]=> array(2) 
            {
                ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 3" ["vote_number"]=> string(2) "20"
            } [4]=> array(2) 
            {
                ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 4" ["vote_number"]=> string(2) "30" 
            } [5]=> array(2) 
            {
                ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 5" ["vote_number"]=> string(2) "40" 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I want to extract values from the above Nested array.
Like

```
$title_data = [Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4,Title 5];

$vote_data  = [5,10,20,30,40];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_column()` should do the trick.

```
$title_data = array_column($data_array[0], 'title');
$vote_data = array_column($data_array[0], 'vote_number');
```

then you can merge the array together with `implode()`

```
$title_data = implode(',', $title_data);
$vote_data = implode(',', $vote_data);
```

Comment: One liner:https://3v4l.org/rIJe8

Comment: How I can get title within the double quotation `"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5", "Title 6", "Title 7"`

Comment: @Firefog you will need array_map on the first result (before implode) e.g. $title_data = array_map($title_data, function($title) { return '"$title"'; });

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$array = 
    [
        [
            ["title"=> "Title 1", "vote_number"=>"5"],
            ["title"=> "Title 2", "vote_number"=>"15"],
            ["title"=> "Title 3", "vote_number"=>"10"],
            ["title"=> "Title 4", "vote_number"=>"7"],
            ["title"=> "Title 5", "vote_number"=>"3"],
            ["title"=> "Title 6", "vote_number"=>"9"],
        ]
    ];
$titles = [];
$votes = [];

foreach($array[0] as $arr) {
    $titles[] = $arr["title"];
    $votes[] = $arr["vote_number"];
}
print_r($titles);
print_r($votes);
```

And output is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Title 1
    [1] => Title 2
    [2] => Title 3
    [3] => Title 4
    [4] => Title 5
    [5] => Title 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 9
)
```